# Help installing rpx module

Tags: 7

I'm trying to use the [RPX module](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) and I get as far as step 5.

I've installed and enabled the plug 
[image]

checked permissions
[image]

and selected "visitors"

[image]

Then i get here.

> Visit admin/config/people/rpx and enter your Janrain Engage API key.* This API key must be entered for the module to function properly.

I find that the path admin/config/people/rpx doesn't exist.

I'm running Drupal 7.12 with RPX 7.x-2.2

Is this a common problem, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Just open the `rpx.module` file and search for hook_menu and find link !

Comment: @NikhilMohan is that suppose to give me a correct link or something ?

Comment: Yes, this hook is used for defining urls, that they supposed to use. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: open 'rpx_ui.module' in line 17 you can see that url defined. Try clear your cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install `7.x-2.2` version and follow structures, `admin/config/people/rpx` exists and work correctly.

this may cause because of bad/in-complete installation, install DEVEL module and try: clear cache / re-install / re-build menu

Comment: i completely removed the module and reinstalled no luck

Comment: do you try re-build menu / clear cache? you should re-install using devel module. do you use devel?

Comment: How does one re-install a module "using devel"?

Comment: go to `devel/reinstall`: http://localhost/devel/reinstall

Comment: i do not use devel but i could try it

Answer (score 3):

The page you are referring to, `admin/config/people/rpx`, is defined in the module named `Janrain Engage UI`, machine name `rpx_ui`. You need to have it enabled for the path to be registered.

Comment: i added screen shots , I believe those pieces of the module are enabled